# Git - How to automatically ignore a file after a clone?

Tags: git

I would know if there is a way to include a file in a repo, but that it is automatically ignored after the user cloned the repo..

It would be great for configuration files: once you clone the repo, you just edit it (and you don't have to remember to put it in .gitignore)

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way to do this since git (by default after cloning) tracks all changes to indexed files. A workaround is having a small script (e.g., `bootstrap.sh`) that generates the config files, and have the generated files `.gitignored`.

Comment: This is the best answer I got :-)
The key here is the fact that there isn't a way to deal automatically, so we're done here :-)

Comment: Remember that if you're unsatisfied with all current answers, [self answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) are explicitly encouraged. You may want to do so to have an accepted answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

One way is to run
`git update-index --assume-unchanged filename.txt`

Another way is to commit template versions of the files, do your clone, copy the templates and have the copied files in your .gitignore.

Unfortunately both approaches require you to do something after cloning.

Answer (score 2):

There are several options:

#### Add the file to `.gitignore` file

This will ignore the file and any changes made to it.

#### `--assume-unchaged`

Raise the `--assume-unchaged` flag on this file so it will stop tracking changes on this file

> #### ***`--[no-]assume-unchanged`***
>
> When this flag is specified, the object names recorded for the paths are not updated.
>
> Instead, this option sets/unsets the `assume unchanged` bit for the paths.
>
> When the `assume unchanged` bit is **on**, the user promises not to change the file and allows Git to assume that the working tree file matches what is recorded in the index. If you want to change the working tree file, you need to unset the bit to tell Git. This is sometimes helpful when working with a big project on a filesystem that has very slow lstat(2) system call (e.g. cifs).
>
> Git will fail (gracefully) in case it needs to modify this file in the index e.g. when merging in a commit; thus, in case the assumed-untracked file is changed upstream, you will need to handle the situation manually.

[image]