# Git: Include file in git clone but ignore any local changes to it?

Tags: git, environment-variables, gitignore

Git question! Is it possible to ignore local changes to a file but still include the file when the project is cloned?

There's a template in our repo for our `.env` file. That looks like this:

```
#########################
# ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES #
#########################

NODE_ENV=local
PORT=8000
MYSQL_USERNAME=root
MYSQL_PASSWORD=
MYSQL_WRITE_HOST=localhost
MYSQL_READ_HOSTS_LIST=localhost
MYSQL_PORT=3306
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
(... etc)
```

We'd like for new devs to receive it when they `git clone`.

They'll be populating missing fields locally, and we do not want them to accidentally commit access keys, etc.

Will putting `.env` in our .gitignore file prevent the file from being included in a `git clone`?

Comment: The short answer is no: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/36461882/1256452 for the usual solutions if you insist on this particular approach. The usual "best practice" approach seems to be *put the configuration elsewhere, have the repository include a default configuration, and have the software install the default configuration automatically in the real configuration if and only if needed and appropriate.*